# Building Hadoop with native windows binaries on azure devops windows agent

Tags: windows, maven, hadoop, azure-devops

Due to security obligations in my firm they refused to use the prebuilt hadoop.dll and winutils in order to add them in path and be able to develop locally.

So I forked the https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/release-3.2.2-RC5 and based on this tutorial [Build and Install Hadoop on Windows With Native Binaries - DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/build-and-install-hadoop-on-windows-with-native-bi)

I wrote this yaml script in order to prepare the steps mentioned in the tutorial. Since I was not able to add the protoc to the system env variables i just downloaded it and put it in the project directory so it was able to find it. I also used the maven protoc.exe since the version 2.5.0 no longer exists in the protobuf releases.

Another thing was to workaround and error of MsBuild version 100 I had to retarget the project to MSBuild v142 by downloading it and retargeting it locally, and then modified the winutils.pojxcv file manually on my distant repo.

Here is the yaml:

```
    trigger:
- master
 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
 
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install Cygwin'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      choco install cygwin -y
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Test cygwin'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      uname -a
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install Windows SDK'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      choco install windows-sdk-10.0 -y
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
- task : Bash@3
  displayName: 'Install Protoc'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        #!/bin/bash
 
        downloadUrl=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/2.5.0/protoc-2.5.0-windows-x86_64.exe
        outputDir="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        mkdir -p $outputDir
        curl -L -o "$outputDir/protoc.exe" $downloadUrl
        ls -al "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
       
        protocPath="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/protoc.exe"
 
        output=$("$protocPath" --version)
        if [[ "$output" =~ "libprotoc 2.5.0" ]]; then
          echo "Protoc version 2.5.0 installed successfully"
        else
          echo "Error: Protoc version mismatch or command failed"
          exit 1
        fi
 
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'List environment variables'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem Env: | Sort-Object Name | Format-Table Name, Value -AutoSize
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Test cMake'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cmake --version
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Build Parent Project'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\pom.xml'
    options: '-Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -X'
    goals: 'clean package'
```

The issue am having is when i try to package the solution i got this error :

```
INFO] Executing tasks
Build sequence for target(s) `main' is [main]
Complete build sequence is [main, ]

main:
Property "BUILD_DIR" has not been set
Property "BUILD_DIR" has not been set
Property "snappy.lib" has not been set
Property "openssl.lib" has not been set
Property "BUILD_DIR" has not been set
Property "BUILD_DIR" has not been set
Property "snappy.lib" has not been set
Property "openssl.lib" has not been set
     [exec] Current OS is Windows Server 2019
     [exec] Executing 'bash' with arguments:
     [exec] './dist-copynativelibs.sh'
     [exec] 
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'bash' with arguments:
'./dist-copynativelibs.sh'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [exec] Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
     [exec] Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
     [exec] https://aka.ms/wslstore
     [exec] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Apache Hadoop Main 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [ 15.697 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  4.240 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  4.108 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [ 13.099 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.125 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... FAILURE [  0.954 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SKIPPED
.....
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: -1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="bash">... @ 41:88 in D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: -1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="bash">... @ 41:88 in D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: -1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="bash">... @ 41:88 in D:\a\1\s\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:355)
```

I would really appreciate your help. I can see that it is unable to execute the bash script in the pom.xml under the antrun-plugin but why? is it a cygwin issue? or am i missing something?
Thank you

Comment: `executable="bash"`? That's not going to work on windows. I don't think your maven task is using Cygwin because it doesn't need to